# instagram api - reach and engagement

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, social-media

I checked the documentation for the Instagram API: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

The problem is that I can't find an endpoint to retrieve the reach (how many unique people saw a specific post) nor an endpoint to retrieve the number of engaged people.

For example, on Facebook these 2 metrics are called
`post_impressions_unique` and `post_engaged_users`.

The question is if you know a way to get those metrics using the Instagram API? If not, is it going to be possible in the near future?

Comment: There is no API for that data, if its not in API documentation, its not there :)

Answer (score 3):

2020 and it's totally possible now:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/insights

For example

`GET graph.facebook.com/17841405822304914/insights
 ?metric=impressions,reach,profile_views
 &period=day`

Comment: Its giving me error {'error': {'code': 100,
           'fbtrace_id': '################',
           'message': '(#100) permission denied',
           'type': 'OAuthException'}}

Comment: Have you tried adding a token in the end like so `&access_token=IGQVJ...` ?

Comment: Yes I tried, got same error. But now its working, some permissions were missing. Thanks :)

Comment: @monikamunjal try to add permission for your app from graph api.  for example: instagram_manage_insights